# What bound does the Hamming bound give you for the largest possible size of a $t$-error-correcting code of length $2t + 1$?

Tags: coding-theory

Let $\mathbb{A}$ = $\{0, 1\}$ and suppose $t$ is a positive integer. What bound does the Hamming bound give you for the largest possible size of a $t$-error correcting code of length $2t+1$?

I have equation

$$
|C|\le \frac{q^n}{{n\choose0}+{(q-1)}{n\choose1}+\cdots+{(q-1)^t}{n\choose{t}}}
$$

with addition to the $2^n=\sum_{r=0}^n{n\choose{r}}$

I get answer $|C| \le 1$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Note that `{a\over b}` is deprecated by `\frac{a}{b}` and `{n\choose k}` by `\binom{n}{k}`. Also `$a$$\le$$b$` is the same but less performant and less readable in plain text than `$a\le b$`. For some more reference see e.g. [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: The question is Let A = {0,1} and suppose t is a positive integer. What bound does the Hamming bound give you for the largest possible size of a t-error correcting code of length 2t+1?

Comment: What is the relevance of $\mathbb A$ to the question since you don't mention $\mathbb A$ again after defining it?

Comment: I missed the bit $n=2t+1$. Very sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the equation you gave for the Hamming bound, $n$ is the length of the code and $q$ is the size of the alphabet. In your case, $n=2t+1$ and $q=|\mathbb{A}|=2$. Substituting $q=2$ in the bound:

$$
|C|
\le \frac{2^n}{\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \ldots + \binom{n}{t}}
= \frac{2^{n}}{\binom{2t+1}{0} + \binom{2t+1}{1} + \ldots + \binom{2t+1}{t}}.
$$

To evaluate the denominator, you can use the other equation you listed:

$$\begin{align}
2^n &= \sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}\\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{2t+1} \binom{2t+1}{r}\\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{t} \binom{2t+1}{r} + \sum_{r=t+1}^{2t+1} \binom{2t+1}{r}\\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{t} \binom{2t+1}{r} + \sum_{r=t+1}^{2t+1} \binom{2t+1}{(2t+1)-r}\\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{t} \binom{2t+1}{r} + \sum_{r=0}^{t} \binom{2t+1}{r}\\
&= 2 \sum_{r=0}^{t} \binom{2t+1}{r}\\
&= 2 \left(\binom{2t+1}{0} + \binom{2t+1}{1} + \ldots + \binom{2t+1}{t}\right).
\end{align}$$

The fourth line is the critical step: $\binom{i}{j} = \binom{i}{i-j}$.

Once you've found an upper bound on $|C|$, you should try to find a binary $t$-error-correcting code of length $2t+1$ which meets that bound.